# Error: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest - NotFound

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a C# application that creates Microsoft Teams using the Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient. I'm using application permissions, not delegated. This code works most of the time, but every now and again I get the following error:

> Code: NotFound
>
> Message: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/amer/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: NotFound, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
>
> x-operationid: c9048cffce324e439c1c94d4b1318d00
>
> x-telemetryid: 00-c9048cffce324e439c1c94d4b1318d00-ed986926db9ed739-01
>
> X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 066FB851BEEE428880666D77A85691E1 Ref B: SJC211051205051 Ref C: 2024-01-03T18:59:47Z
>
> Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2024 18:59:47 GMT
>
> ErrorMessage : {"errors":[{"message":"Error when calling Middle Tier. Message: ''. Error code: 'NotFound'. Status code: NotFound.","errorCode":"Unknown"}],"operationId":"c9048cffce324e439c1c94d4b1318d00"}

Even when the code fails, if I run it again it usually works. Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
var team = new Team
{
            Visibility = TeamVisibilityType.Public,
            DisplayName = teamName,
            Description = teamDescription,
            MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings

            {
                AllowCreateUpdateChannels = true,
                AllowDeleteChannels = true,
                AllowAddRemoveApps = true,
                AllowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs = true,
                AllowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors = true
            },

            GuestSettings = new TeamGuestSettings
            {
                AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false,
                AllowDeleteChannels = false
            },
            FunSettings = new TeamFunSettings
            {
                AllowGiphy = true,
                GiphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.Moderate,
                AllowStickersAndMemes = true,
                AllowCustomMemes = true
            },

            MessagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings
            {
                AllowUserEditMessages = true,
                AllowUserDeleteMessages = true,
                AllowOwnerDeleteMessages = true,
                AllowTeamMentions = true,
                AllowChannelMentions = true
            },

            Members = members,
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
            }
        };

        var teamResponse = await graphServiceClient.Teams
            .Request()
            .WithAppOnly()
            .AddResponseAsync(team);
```

Here is how the members section gets generated:

```
new TeamMembersCollectionPage()
        {
            new AadUserConversationMember
            {
                Roles = new List<String>()
                {
                    "owner"
                },

                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"user@odata.bind", $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{ownerUpn}')"}
                }
            }
        };
```

I think the NotFound part of the error may be referring to the owner that I'm adding to the Team, but in all cases, that user does exist, and as I said before, simply re-running the code usually fixes the issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I am trying to create a Microsoft Team with an assigned Owner using the Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient in C#. Sometimes it errors out. Other times it works. Re-running the code usually works.

Comment: The error message "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest - NotFound" indicates that the API call to create a team from a template was not successful because the template was not found.
Could you please ensure that the template you are trying to use exists and is accessible?

Comment: The template as in the standard template? In the AdditionalData section I set the "template@odata.bind" to this template "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"

Comment: Are you getting the same error response when you are trying via Postman?

Comment: In production, this code runs in an Azure App Service with some protection so it can't be called from Postman, so instead I run the code locally and change the connection strings to point to the production environment. It usually works when I re-run the code using this method, but it still fails sometimes with the same error. Then I wait a bit and try again and it works.

Comment: Hello Mike - The user id whichever mentioned in user@odata.bind need to correct. If the user is not present of that id, then NotFound error will come. So please make sure that everytime you are passing the correct user id.

Comment: Hello @MikeK - Could you please also share the client-request-id and timestamp so that engineering team can check on it from their end?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - I've confirmed that the user does exist. The error hasn't happened in a while, but here is one request that failed:

date: 2024-01-19T17:56:22
client-request-id: b191d413-635e-43d4-a233-78bc03e0959c

Comment: Hello @MikeK we have Raised a ICM for this issue.